# WASM (ImageMagick) based code blocks Deno Server

Tags: server, imagemagick, webassembly, deno

Below in my first example is a simple web server using deno's new `serve` api. If you open up curl and run `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8000` quickly in two tabs. You'll see the expected result

```
request made ✅
request made ✅
request served 
request served
```

Here's the code that outputs the logs above:

```
import { reservedPath } from "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/reggi/f989eb2b395fa348595a2ec2a7099e95/raw/bf0e75061f2e2454a244cef019ffac2cf1fc38fc/reserved_path.ts";

const file = await Deno.readFile('./image.png')

function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

Deno.serve(async (_req) => {
  console.log(`request made ✅`)
  if (reservedPath(_req.url)) {
    return new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
  }
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
  await delay(300)
  console.log(`request served `)
  return new Response(file, { headers });
})
```

However I'm facing an issue specifically with a wasm build of ImageMagick [magick-wasm](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm) which is used wrapped in [imagemagick-deno](https://github.com/lumeland/imagemagick-deno) for some convenience files and converting the codebase to use `.ts` files directly.

Here's a working server, when I open up http://localhost:8000/ I get the image, however when I run curl I get the output below. Which means to me, this code is blocking the server. It means that users on the server block each other. This WASM ImageMagick library does seem to allow parallel non-blocking code (as long as it doesn't return) as seen [here](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm/issues/106#issuecomment-1656126707) with that knowledge I tried to force a server to stream an empty readable stream, then use update the stream with the image when it was finished processing, this didn't work either.

```
request made ✅
request served 
request made ✅
request served
```

Here's the code:

```
import { reservedPath } from "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/reggi/f989eb2b395fa348595a2ec2a7099e95/raw/bf0e75061f2e2454a244cef019ffac2cf1fc38fc/reserved_path.ts";
import { CompositeOperator, Gravity, ImageMagick, Point, initializeImageMagick } from "https://deno.land/x/imagemagick_deno@0.0.19/mod.ts";

const file = await Deno.readFile('./image.png')

await initializeImageMagick()

Deno.serve((_req) => {
  console.log(`request made ✅`)
  if (reservedPath(_req.url)) {
    return new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
  }
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
  const i = ImageMagick.read(file, (v) => {
    v.compositeGravity(v, Gravity.North, CompositeOperator.Overlay, new Point(-20, -20))
    v.compositeGravity(v, Gravity.North, CompositeOperator.Overlay, new Point(20, 20))
    return v.write(g => g)
  })
  console.log(`request served `)
  return new Response(i, { headers });
})
```

`ImageMagick.read` requires a callback, it seems it returns whatever it returns, so it returns a promise if I return a promise from within. It's kind of both sync and async at the same time. It's kind of confusing to ration about. I've tried many combinations of making different callbacks within it async and waiting various stages of that code, I'm not sure that's the issue. At first glance if I were you I'd be confused by that part, but I think it's a red-herring I think there's something deeper going on.

Is there something specific within `Deno.serve` causing this? Is this something known that WASM code does?

Comment: JS is single-threaded, so synchronous code (the `ImageMagick` task) will always block the main thread, which is your server — regardless of the callback. If you want to avoid that, you’ll have to use a pattern that performs the task off of the main thread (e.g. in a [`Worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)). Does that address your question? If so, I can write it as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn I think you perfectly understand the problem, workers! I didn't even think about that I went to child process routed and hit a problem with deno deploy. If you want to post a solution I'll market as the correct answer.

Comment: @jsejcksn I got this working locally at least using workers, the question is will this work on deno deploy , quite a bit of boilerplate to demo you don't need a working example for me to +1 ur answer.

Comment: Doesn't work on deploy ☠️ ReferenceError: Worker is not defined

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76791229/wasm-imagemagick-based-code-blocks-deno-server/76791741#comment135379557_76791229) The question doesn't mention the Deno Deploy platform (which significantly changes the context of the question). I mentioned using a worker as one example of an off-thread pattern (compared with IPC, another network request, etc.). Deploy is unique in that every request is handled by a dedicated isolate process, so the blocking of a common, persistent server process won't be an issue (because there is no persistent server process in that environment).

Comment: Would you still like to see all of this as an answer — does it address your question at this point or am I missing something else?

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't believe it's true that every request is independent on deno deploy some requests are batched on the same machine, and the same thread. So I think this will still be a problem.

Comment: @jsejcksn I posted a issue on deno deploy's github  https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/458

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Why do you claim that requests are batched on a shared Deploy process?

Comment: @jsejcksn because that's what I've been told and witnessed numerous times, here's more reading on it https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/458#issuecomment-1659875105

Comment: In that case, it looks like your only option with Deploy might be to create multiple instances for load balancing, and create one instance as the ingress point, which will delegate to the others.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now (JUL 28 2023) this does not work on deno deploy.

> server.ts

```
import { reservedPath } from "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/reggi/f989eb2b395fa348595a2ec2a7099e95/raw/bf0e75061f2e2454a244cef019ffac2cf1fc38fc/reserved_path.ts";

const file = await Deno.readFile('./image.png')

Deno.serve((_req) => {
  console.log(`request made ✅`)
  if (reservedPath(_req.url)) {
    return new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 })
  }
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
  const worker = new Worker(new URL("./worker.ts", import.meta.url).href, {
    type: "module",
    name: "worker-" + (100 * Math.random()).toFixed(),
  });

  worker.postMessage({ task: { byteArray: file } });

  // Wait for a response from the worker to be fulfilled
  // Fulfill the promise when the mesage is passed.
  const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    worker.onmessage = (msg) => {
      resolve(msg.data);
    };
    worker.onerror = (err) => {
        err.preventDefault();
      reject(err.message);
    };
  });

  return result.then((output: any) => {
    console.log(`request served `)
    console.log({ output })
    return new Response(output, { headers });
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.log("Caught reason");
    return Response.json({
      reason,
    }, {
      status: 400,
    });
  })
  .finally(() => worker.terminate());
});
```

> worker.ts

```
/// <reference no-default-lib="true" />
/// <reference lib="deno.worker" />
import { CompositeOperator, Gravity, ImageMagick, Point, initializeImageMagick } from "https://deno.land/x/imagemagick_deno@0.0.19/mod.ts";

type WorkerParams = {
  byteArray: Uint8Array
}

await initializeImageMagick()
console.log("worker starting");

self.onmessage = (evt) => {
  const { task }: { task: WorkerParams } = evt.data;
  console.log("worker received task", task);
  return ImageMagick.read(task.byteArray, (v) => {
    v.compositeGravity(v, Gravity.North, CompositeOperator.Overlay, new Point(-20, -20))
    v.compositeGravity(v, Gravity.North, CompositeOperator.Overlay, new Point(20, 20))
    return v.write(g => {
      return self.postMessage(g);
    })
  })
};
```